# Resource Skus API returns conflicting information

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

We are using the ResourceSkus API to get the available VMs for a Subscription in a particular region. However, I see some strange behavior for the F2S_v2 size in southeastasia. The API returns info saying the size is available and restricted at the same time. When checking the availability, should i trust the locationInfo field or the restrictions field?

```
{
    "resourceType": "virtualMachines",
    "name": "Standard_F2s_v2",
    "tier": "Standard",
    "size": "F2s_v2",
    "family": "standardFSv2Family",
    "kind": null,
    "capacity": null,
    "locations": [ "southeastasia" ],
    "locationInfo": [
      {
        "location": "southeastasia",
        "zones": [ "3" ]
      }
    ],
    "apiVersions": null,
    "costs": null,
    "capabilities": [

    ],
    "restrictions": [
      {
        "type": "Zone",
        "values": [ "southeastasia" ],
        "restrictionInfo": {
          "locations": [ "southeastasia" ],
          "zones": [ "1", "2", "3" ]
        },
        "reasonCode": "NotAvailableForSubscription"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that there are two types of restrictions: `Zone` and `Location`. `Zone` indicates that the VM size cannot be used in availability zones in that location. Where `Location` indicates that the size is not available in that location.